# Zero-scaled displacement image distorts Sprite on container rotation: Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a simple `Pixi.js` scene where there are 4 Sprites vertically placed. All of them have a **displacement image** assigned. To begin the sketch, I have set the **displacement image** to **scale 0** so the Sprite doesn't appear distorted by default. The Sprites are perfect rectangles when **parent container** is not rotated, but when the **parent container** is rotated, the Sprite gets some displacement/cropping applied on corners. How do I remove this displacement at sketch start?

I have attached the screenshot and encircled the croppy parts.

And this is the code:

```
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;

const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    transparent: false,
    antialias: true
});

app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0x404040;

// making the canvas responsive
window.onresize = () => {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;
    app.renderer.resize(width, height);
}

app.renderer.view.style.position = 'absolute';
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

let pContainer= new PIXI.Container();
pContainer.pivot.set(-width/2, -350);
pContainer.rotation = -0.3; // This rotation distorts the Sprites

app.stage.addChild(pContainer);

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    let container = new PIXI.Container();
    container.pivot.y = -i * 210;    
    
    let image = new PIXI.Sprite.from('image.jpg');
    image.width = 100;
    image.height = 200;
    image.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);    

    let dispImage = new PIXI.Sprite.from('disp.jpg');
    let dispFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(dispImage);
    dispImage.texture.baseTexture.wrapMode = PIXI.WRAP_MODES.REPEAT;
    container.filters = [dispFilter];     

    // Turn disp scale to zero so it doesnt show distorted image by default
    dispImage.scale.set(0);

    container.addChild(image);
    container.addChild(dispImage);
    pContainer.addChild(container);
}
```

Thank you.

**disp.jpg:**

[image: Displacement map used]

**image.jpg**

[image]

**The Sprites' corners getting distorted. Encircled in yellow**

[image: the issue]

Comment: @domis86 no reply there by anyone.

Comment: ok, try adding minimal reproduction working code on https://www.pixiplayground.com/ or codesandbox etc. This way will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: @domis86 Thank you very much. I'll check them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the simpler fix is to use a rect behind that is bigger than the photo, it can be the screen size too

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my late acceptance.